# Jhon Papa Angular Style guide Factory - Function inside object not running

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use [Jhon Papa's](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#factories) Angular 1 style guide to create a factory in Angularjs. The problem is that when I encapsulate a function in an object and then return this object the function does not get called.

For example

Does not work

```
 angular
  .module('movieCore')
  .factory('PopularMovies', factory);

factory.$inject = ['$resource'];

function factory($resource) {

  var service = {
    popularMovies: popularMovies
  };

  return service;

  function popularMovies() {
    var token = 'teddybear'; // TBC
        return $resource('popular/:movieId', { movieId: '@id' }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: { 'authToken': token }
            },
            get: {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { 'authToken': token }
            },
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { 'authToken': token }
            },
            save: {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'authToken': token }
            },
            remove: {
                method: 'DELETE',
                headers: { 'authToken': token }
            }
        });
  }
}
```

If I remove the object which holds the function it works.

```
angular
  .module('movieCore')
    .factory('PopularMovies', factory);

  factory.$inject = ['$resource'];
  function factory($resource) {

    var token = 'teddybear'; // TBC
    console.log('hey there');
        return $resource('popular/:movieId', { movieId: '@id' }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: { 'authToken': token }
            },
            get: {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { 'authToken': token }
            },
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { 'authToken': token }
            },
            save: {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'authToken': token }
            },
            remove: {
                method: 'DELETE',
                headers: { 'authToken': token }
            }
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one difference, to access the first example you have to write `popularMovies.popularMovies();` in the second you can just write `popularMovies()`. Thats why one example work an the other not. because first example returns you an object with `popularMovies()` as a member. Second example returns directly the `$resource`

Answer (score -1):

Switch the order of the return statement and the function. `popularMovies` is undefined at the time of return:

```
angular
  .module('movieCore')
  .factory('PopularMovies', factory);

factory.$inject = ['$resource'];

function factory($resource) {

  function popularMovies() {
    var token = 'teddybear'; // TBC
        return $resource('popular/:movieId', { movieId: '@id' }, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: { 'authToken': token }
            },
            get: {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { 'authToken': token }
            },
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { 'authToken': token }
            },
            save: {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'authToken': token }
            },
            remove: {
                method: 'DELETE',
                headers: { 'authToken': token }
            }
        });
  }

  return {
    popularMovies: popularMovies
  };
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, functions are *hoisted* in javascript.

Comment: @Cuz is right. this is not the problem. the problem is that the function return the resource but it never get called

Comment: Indeed you guys are right. I was confused with declaring a var as a function, e.g. var popularMovies = function... In this case, declaring the var after the return doesn't work.